# Integrate Moodle with Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, moodle

I want to integrate [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) with Moodle.
I would like Moodle users to be able to store e-content and retrieve them easily using Alfresco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moodle 2.x is already integrated with the Alfresco repository, although this needs to be enabled by an administrator via Site administration -> plugins -> repositories -> manage repositories. The documentation is [here](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Alfresco_repository) and although sparse, provides links to discussions that explain how to get it going.